# Как не писать текст в файл

Tags: c#

```
do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите текст");
            text = Console.ReadLine();

            File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(path), text + Environment.NewLine);
            
        } while (text != "stop");
```

Пользователь печатает текст и когда пользователь вводет stop то введеные текста записываются в файл, но слово stop тоже записывается в файл, как сделать чтобы он не записывался?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смешно, но почему бы не так :)

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введите текст");
    text = Console.ReadLine();

    if( text == "stop" ) break;

    File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(path), text + Environment.NewLine);
};
```

Comment: Благодарствую вам

Answer (score 0):

Смешно но почему бы не так в цикле

```
  do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите текст");
        text = Console.ReadLine();
        if( text != "stop")
          File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(path), text + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        
    } while (text != "stop");
```

Comment: Два раза одно условие проверять не очень красиво )

Comment: Смешно но менять по минимуму его код в данном случае. Просто показываю человеку что значит менять свой код. Чтоб работал. Понятно что писать нужно немного по другому :)). Но ему ещё попадется проектик в котором нельзя переписывать код, а только фиксить баги

Comment: Ну, такое. Потом он будет "фиксить баги", поменяет слово "stop" на какое-то другое в одном месте и будет долго разбираться, в чём прикол )

Comment: @CrazyElf Я лишь показал, я не говорю об истинности в первой инстанции. Показываю как его код доводить до желаемого результата Не говоря вообще как у него возникла такая задача. По хорошему вводить до стоп это то чего в коммерческих проектах не встретишь

Comment: Так что считаю указать на "проблему" нежели переделывать весь код.